# Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS - Reverting an updated package - how?

Tags: ubuntu, package-management

I have Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS and an automated security update updated apache2 from 2.2.14-5ubuntu8.7 to 2.2.14-5ubuntu8.8, how can I revert back to 8.7?

ls /var/cache/apt/archives shows that there is no backup of the old version is left locally.

I need to revert back for testing an issue that might happen because of the new package version. To exclude this possibility I want to revert it back.

Edit: I need to do this on command line, it's a server without GUI.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ubuntu Desktop, you can try using `synaptic`. It has a "Force version" feature that allows to choose between versions that are available from the repos. To use it you need to locate the package, highlight it and click "Force Version..." in the "Package" drop-down menu.

Comment: It's a server without GUI.